Migration RxBroadcast from android 13 to android 14
How to migrate RxBroadcast from android 13 to android 14?
How to resolve security exception:
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
subscriptions.add(RxBroadcast.fromBroadcast(getContext(), intentFilter)

